# Create Java object from from page content or plain text

Tags: java, strings, parsing, json, factory-method

My job is to make a specified java objects from web page that contains following text:

**Companies:**

```
[{"companyName":"Tire Systems","companyID":1},{"companyName":"IT Enterprise","companyID":2},{"companyName":"Car Manufacture","companyID":3},{"companyName":"Electro Market","companyID":4}]
```

**Materials:**

```
[{"name":"Winter Tire","ID":1,"companyID":1},{"name":"Summer Tire","ID":2,"companyID":1},{"name":"Tire","ID":3,"companyID":1},{"name":"Reporting Software","ID":4,"companyID":2},{"name":"Text Editor","ID":5,"companyID":2},{"name":"Passenger Car","ID":6,"companyID":3},{"name":"Truck","ID":7,"companyID":3},{"name":"Pickup","ID":8,"companyID":3},{"name":"Laptop","ID":9,"companyID":4},{"name":"Smartphone","ID":10,"companyID":4},{"name":"Tablet","ID":11,"companyID":4}]
```

This code took me a lot of time to be written and seems to be very complicated and non-efficient in my opinion. Here is source code with my description

```
private static String[][] pageContentToArray(String url, int attr) throws Exception {

    // getPageContent returns code like this [{"attribute":"value","attrubute":value},{"attr":"val","attr":val},...] 
    String[] pageContent = getPageContent(url).split(",");

    //len is attributes amount multipled by objects amount
    int len = pageContent.length;

    String[][] splitedPageContent = new String[len][attr];

    // len/attr returns number of objects
    String[][] groupedPageContent = new String[len/attr][attr];
    int savePoint = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

        //removes all "{}[] characters
        splitedPageContent[i] = pageContent[i].replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","").replaceAll("\"","").split(":");

        // if statement is fullfiled every nth step where n equals attr value
        if (i % attr == (attr-1)) {
            int k = 0;

            //so basically it is reorganising data
            for (int j = attr-1; j >= 0; --j) {
                groupedPageContent[savePoint][k] = splitedPageContent[i-j][1];
                ++k;
            }
            ++savePoint;
        }
    }
    return groupedPageContent;
}
```

This is the basic method that taking page content (described in the beginning). Splits it to array by "," sign then removes all special characters like "{}[] then making 2d array from them by splitting with ":" char.  There is an algorithm works "parallely" that every nth step (when n is amount of attributes) values are reorganized to new 2d array. The final product is an 2d array where first column contains attribute names and the second contains values.

```
public static Company[] pageToCompanies() {
    try {
        String[][] groupedPageContent = pageContentToArray(COMPANY_LIST, 2);
        int len = groupedPageContent.length;
        Company[] companies = new Company[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            companies[i] = new Company(groupedPageContent[i][0], Integer.parseInt(groupedPageContent[i][1]));
        }
        return companies;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        MainFrame.infoBox("Wrong companies page content");
    }
    return null; 

}

public static Material[] pageToMaterials() {
    String[][] groupedPageContent;
    try {
        groupedPageContent = pageContentToArray(MATERIAL_LIST, 3);
        int len = groupedPageContent.length;
        Material[] materials = new Material[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            materials[i] = new Material(
                        groupedPageContent[i][0],
                        Integer.parseInt(groupedPageContent[i][1]),
                        Integer.parseInt(groupedPageContent[i][2])
                    );
        }
        return materials;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            MainFrame.infoBox("Wrong materials page content");
    }
    return null; 
}
```

There are two methods that doing mostly the same thing grab values from 2d array and initialize objects with them. As you can see there is a lot of repeated code. First column of an array is not even used.

**Possible Solution:**
Ideal solutions would be possibilities of:

- passing class type to method as an argument
- evaluate string to variable name just like it has been done in PHP or Bash Scripting (in these languages $var = "name" is String, but $$var is executable code)
- some smart way for converting text to 2D array in one step, I feel
  that it can be done in one or few steps but I does not know how. I
  heard about Pattern class in java but still do not know if it is
  useful in this case

I think there is a way to completely rewrite for having 1 method instead of 3 and making code short, efficient with this solutions, however I am not sure if I would write it perfectly even with that knowledge so every example code will be greatly appreciated.

Or maybe you have another idea how to rewrite my code. I would be grateful for any help. Also sorry for my English it is not my native language.

Comment: You do realize that the text youa re parsing is JSON data.... right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're working too hard.
Although your post title says,
*"Create Java object **from page content or plain text**"*,
actually it appears to be **from JSON**, specifically.
Since it's such a common format,
and it seems you're not actually trying to [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel),
you'd be much better off using one of the existing libraries for the task.
For example [Jackson](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/jackson-create-json.jsp) seems popular.

Other than rewriting your program using Jackson or similar,
some big issues that stand out:

1. Catching `Exception`: you should catch the most specific exception type that can be thrown, `Exception` is way to generic. It doesn't give a clue about what can go wrong with the code, and it can catch other exception types that are truly unexpected.
2. It seems you're overusing exceptions.
   For example in `pageToCompanies`, it's not clear what can throw that exception you're catching,
   and in any case it looks like you should be handling unexpected data with conditionals, not with exceptions.